# How can I "erase" something I've drawn on a Java Graphics2D Canvas without deleting something that's behind it?

Tags: java, swing, awt, graphics2d, jslider

I am writing a program that draws a specific graph (based on parameters given through a JSlider) on a coordinate system.
The issue I'm having is that my coordinate system is also drawn on that canvas, and if I were to use the "clearRect" method, it would delete both the graph that I want to get rid off to draw the new one when the JSlider updates and also the coordinate system.
Is there a way to "lock" the coordinate system so it doesn't get deleted or something like that?

Comment: Simply draw in the `paintComponent(Graphics g)` and in the surrounding JPanel the grid.

Comment: Draw it in XOR mode, and simply redraw it when you want it to disappear.

Answer (score 2):

Do not directly draw to the canvas. Create a list of objects, such as coordinate system, and objects. You can manipulate the list (add or remove objects) and `repaint` canvas when something changes.

Every object in the List can implement an interface `Drawable` with a method say draw(). So the list will be `List<Drawable>`. In the canvas's `paint()` go through all the objects and call draw().